# what is the route table file

Tags: route, ip-routing

When I run the below command, where is it stored? Or it remains in the memory until a reboot?

```
ip rule add from x.x.x.x table 1
```

I just wanted to use a custom name for IPV6 which would separate it from IPv4. So I gave `table eth0V6` which threw an error,

> Error: argument "eth0V6" is wrong: invalid table ID

But then it accepts `table 1` and other numbers. So basically I wanted to check whether I need to create a file with custom name for the V6 route table and at which location. But couldn't find `table 1` being updated anywhere at `/etc/iproute2/`.

Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either numeric table IDs like `1` or you can use named tables like `eth0V6`.

Only named tables require definition in the file `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`. You need to have a line like the following:

```
100     eth0V6
```

In this example, you can use either ID `100` or name `eth0V6`.